# 別に to mean "not particularly"

Tags: meaning

I hear 別に used as "not in particular", did this usage come about just directly from the meaning of "separately"? So when used, it means that someone has a separate interest, like, etc. and hence they don't particularly have the interest, or share the like?

Answer (score 6):

No, this negative expression means "Not really", "I'm not interested", "I don't care", etc.

I think this 「別に…」 is the shortened form of "別に言いたいことはない" or "別にそういうわけではない", and 別に here roughly corresponds to *particularly*.

Something positive, like "これとは別のものが好きです" or "私はこれとは別に、言いたいことがあります" is not what the speaker want to say.

Comment: Naruto's answer sounds good to me. I think Naruto's English translation ("Not really", "I don't care" etc.) conveys this well, but I also want to explicitly note that I've been told 別に could come off as rude, curt or at least very casual when used in reply to someone asking about a potential interest. (Please someone let me know if you disagree!)

Comment: @Monburan Yes, "別に" can be very rude, and the best-known example is [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IXpYtOFe9jk). But a single-word answer is always rude in an interview anyway :)